# TextInputLayout text header gone when using FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-textinputlayout

This is my current xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emailAddressLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:clickable="false">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:hint="email address"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:maxLines="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/emailTextClearButton"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_svg" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I need my `FrameLayout` in order to accomplish a (x) clear button within my AutoCompleteTextView.

The problem is that the `FrameLayout` is negating the effect of `TextInputLayout` so the text is not pushed up when user inputs text or clicks on `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Current result: (Missing Email address header text)

[image]

Wanted result: (I added an x clear button to show what's missing when not using `FrameLayout`)

[image]

Comment: Check this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText. You can modify the view according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my question using the following in my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emailAddressTextInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
                            style="@style/body_text_style"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:hint="@string/prompt_email_address"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:maxLines="1"/>

                        <!--work around solution using negative marginTop-->
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/emailTextClearButton"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            //work around solution
                            android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_svg"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The **WORKAROUND** is to set my `button` underneath my `AutoCompleteTextView` and use a **negative marginTop** on the button to be able to set it where it needs to be set.

Result:

[image]

**Note**: I'm using a `RelativeLayout` as parent of `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 1):

`TextInputLayout` has some internal behavior that isn't exactly what you'd expect from a "normal" `ViewGroup`. Most of it is undocumented, but [the Javadoc for the class itself](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java#111) does tell you a little bit:

> **Note:** The actual view hierarchy present under `TextInputLayout` is **NOT** guaranteed to match the view hierarchy as written in XML. As a result, calls to `getParent()` on children of the `TextInputLayout` -- such as an `TextInputEditText` -- may not return the `TextInputLayout` itself, but rather an intermediate `View`. If you need to access a `View` directly, set an `android:id` and use `View#findViewById(int)`.

What you should take away from this is that `TextInputLayout` will both potentially "re-write" your declared XML layout and *also* that you should do your best to make sure that your XML layout is set up in the way `TextInputLayout` "expects".

I believe that your specific problem stems from the fact that your XML layout specifies no `EditText` that is a direct child of the `TextInputLayout`. If you look at [the source for `TextInputLayout#addView()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java#271), you'll see this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void addView(View child, int index, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
>     if (child instanceof EditText) {
>         ...
>         setEditText((EditText) child);
>     } else {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Because you have a `FrameLayout` wrapping the `EditText`, that call to `setEditText()` is never made. Therefore, none of the special functionality of `TextInputLayout` will work.

How to solve this is a more difficult question. I would start by changing your layout to have this structure instead:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <TextInputLayout>
        <EditText/>
    </TextInputLayout>
    <Button/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This way you can have a "normal" `TextInputLayout` hierarchy **and** a button to clear the text. You'll have to do a little more work to position the button so that everything looks natural, but this should be a workable starting point.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a work around like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714083/5544859